# How to import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel on a console application?

Tags: vb.net, excel, console-application, office-interop

It works fine on my Website Application, but I have to use it too on console application that will run from the task scheduler.

This is how I'm calling the import:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Problem is when I try to import it from the console app, I get this error:

```
Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should [`Add Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx) to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` component

Answer (score 3):

with Visual Studio 2013 the answer to this question is to add reference:

Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library